# Debian jessie without desktop

Tags: linux, debian, boot, gnome, desktop

So, I installed debian Jessie on my computer. And it does not have any desktop. I have used numerous of different commands but it just say cannot be found. Thanks for the help.  EDIT! One way to fix my problem is using linux mint USB stick I have. But it does not boot it. I have other computer to use if needed. And at start bios I only have 1. Debian at the list.

Comment: Just for information. I have linux mint iso USB. But debian does not run the installer. Which is main reason I try to Install X.

Comment: Still looking for answer.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably done a minimal installation of Debian, without X Window (what you call "desktop").  As the root user, type this at the shell prompt:

```
apt-get install gnome
```

This will install GNOME on your machine.

If you prefer to install KDE instead:

```
apt-get install kde-full
```

Just for your information, this will add several hundreds of Mb of software on your machine.  This is in no way a problem unless your Linux box is pretty tight in specifications.

EDIT: It looks like your network repositories are not configured.  Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` so it contain this:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

Comment: Type `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.  This will change the language to English.  Then run apt-get again and paste the output here.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information...Done E: Unable to locate package gnome

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: I tried to add comment but  it failed. It basically says: http://'s failed to verify. A network was not selected during install. And that i should amend entries as appropriate for my mirror choice

Comment: I've edited the answer, please try it and let us know.

Comment: So I edited them using 'nano' and tried agter that using apt-get install gnome and it gave reading package lists... Done building dependency tree reading state information... Done E:unable to locate package gnome

Comment: @laguce After changing the package repository settings, you must `apt-get update` before you can meaningfully do anything else. Did you do that?

Comment: @dr01 This answer isn't complete without mentioning `xfce4`. Those three pretty much cover all major setups.

Comment: @laguce Also sometimes you have to "comment out" the CD source in sources.list like in this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/42441/how-do-remove-the-cd-dvd-install-as-a-source-for-apt-get-packages-when-install), I think it has this line when you install without setting up networking. And here are installation guides for [Debian](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/installmanual)

Comment: @Michael Kjörling I did apt-get update now and it says that it failed to fetch htttpredir sites and it couldnt resolve them. Some index files failed to download and it ignored or used old ones instead..